# How to add js media file in ModelAdmin class

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have created ModelAdmin class inside I have defined media class for js file but when I am running my admin site I am not getting any response what I want to see.

here is my app **admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Applications, Country, State


# modeladmin have several attribute used to coustmize model view in admin dashboard

class ApplicationsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields = ('name', 'country', 'state', 'city')

    class Media:
        js = 'asd.js'

admin.site.register(Applications, ApplicationsAdmin)
```

**asd.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id_country").change(function(){
  country_id = $(this).val();
  var url = $("#ApplicationForm").attr("data-states-url");
    console.log((country_id));
    var countryId = country_id
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
                  'country': countryId},
                success: function (data) {
<!--                console.log(data)-->
                $("#id_state").html(data);
                }
        });

  });

});
```

**models.py**

```
class Applications(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

is there any other way to do it or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions) you need to set the js in your Media as an interable, e.g. js = ('asd.js', )

Answer (score 0):

`js` should be an iterable, use this:

```py
class Media:
    js = ('admin/js/useradminjs.js',) # Specify path to your js file
```